# Custom Text Under Navigation Links

Tags: plugins, pages

My navigation bar of my wordpress theme is set up to wp_list_pages.  I'd like to display text underneath those page links.

Like:

---

Home

"Home Sweet Home"

---

Do I need a widget to accomplish this or is it relatively simple to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use a custom walker. You must modify the function that traverse the page and output the HTML. Extend the basic wordpress class and implement your function.

See [this stackechange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/how-to-style-current-page-menu-item-when-using-a-walker) for a code example.

Note: I suggest you to use wp_nav_menu (custom menus) instead of wp_list_page and use the item description as your sub_menu item description.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the WP Admin panel as I should be.  Where can I change the links wp_nav_menu displays?

Comment: Using Appereance -> Menus, you can chose via drag and drop the pages. The link is the permalink of the page. If you want custom links, use the box custom links. To enter a description , enable the field Description in Screen Options

Comment: Thanks, that was easy!  Walkers however are not.  Is there a tutorial out there you recommend?  I've already google'd a few but I want to make sure I'm getting correct, up to date information.

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039) for an example. I’ll keep it up to date if WordPress changes anything related.